# Creating a simple book library system in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to create a simple book library system in C++ (oop style) but from the first Class I've encountered some design programs.

Here is my little Books class .h file (just a draft let's say).

```
#ifndef BOOKS_H
#define BOOKS_H

#include <string>

class Books
{
public:
    Books();
    ~Books() {};
    void createBook();
    //void getBook();


private:
    std::string mBookName;
    std::string mBookAuthor;
    int mId;
};
#endif
```

I'd like to create Books and add them to a file.

My problem/question is as follows:

Should I use data members for Author and Title or just update a file with a function like the one below ?

```
void Books::createBook()
{
    std::string bookAuthor;
    std::string bookName;

    std::cout << "Enter the book Author\n";
    std::getline (std::cin, bookAuthor);
    //write to file bookAuthor
    std::cout << "Enter the book name\n";
    std::getline (std::cin, bookName);
    //write to file bookName
    mId++;
   //write to file mId;

}
```

I'm thinking that if I have a data member Author and data member Title, then If I were to add books to the file I would then to write in `main` function as many book objects as there are books and it would complicate the code a lot..

Instead I'm thinking of doing:

```
int main()
{
   Book newBook;
   //some code to ask to user to enter an option to add a new book
   newBook.createBook();
   //rest of the code
   return 0;
}
```

So... which option is better?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `Books` object can only hold one book.

Comment: so I should have another class or something that allows me to store Book objects?

Comment: _"Should I use data members for Author and Title or just update a file with a function like the one below ?"_ No, such is horrible. It tightly couples your `Book` class to input made from the console. Provide getter/setter functions instead to encapsulate private data, and use these from outside of your class.

Comment: Use a loop in your main, ask the console question there, use the setters like @πάνταῥεῖ said, store that new instance in a `std::vector`

Comment: @Sabyc90 `std::vector<Book>` -- Start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by thinking how a real library works.

You can go to the library and find books by a particular author.
You can go to the library and find books with a particular name.

Each book is itself a distinct object, with a constant name and author.

As such, I'd model this as a single `Library` object, which contains multiple `Book` objects.

The `Library` interface allows you to add a book, find all books with a given name, find all books by a given author, etc.

The `Book` interface allows you to find out a book's name and it's author.

The library is going to have to manage a collection of books. I would try to leverage the STL for my collection of books, as this should be your first go-to resource for data structures in C++.

A [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) allows you to store **key/value** pairs. The `key` would be something like the book's name or author - something you want to use to look up books with.

The `value` is the book itself.

In this particular instance I would choose a [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap), as this allows more than one of the same `key`. This is because you can get more than one book by the same author, and you can get more than one book with the same name.

I would have one `multimap` per `key` I want to search for - so here I'd have 2 - one for books keyed on name, and one for books keyed on author.

`multimap` has a member function [`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) which allows us to find all values with the same key.

It returns two iterators describing a range of values with the specified key.

You could then add additional interfaces to your `Library` class which allows you to save all the books to a file, or load them from a file etc.

Something like the following:

### Book:

```
class Book
{
public:
    Book(std::string author, std::string name)
        : _author(std::move(author))
        , _name(std::move(name))
    {}

    const std::string& author() const { return _author; }
    const std::string& name() const { return _name; }

private:
    const std::string _author;
    const std::string _name;
};
```

### Library:

```
class Library
{
    using BookMap = std::multimap<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Book>>;

public:
    void loadFromFile(const std::string& filename);
    void saveToFile  (const std::string& filename);

    void addBook(std::string name, std::string author)
    {
        auto book = std::make_shared<Book>(std::move(name), std::move(author));

        _books_by_name.emplace(book->name(), book); 
        _books_by_author.emplace(book->author(), book); 
    }

    std::pair<BookMap::const_iterator, BookMap::const_iterator> findByName(const std::string& name)
    {
        return _books_by_name.equal_range(name);
    }

    std::pair<BookMap::const_iterator, BookMap::const_iterator> findByAuthor(const std::string& author)
    {
        return _books_by_author.equal_range(author);
    }

private:
    BookMap _books_by_name;
    BookMap _books_by_author;
}
```